# Json Api values 0 or false

Tags: c#, json, parsing, console-application

I am using a web JSON api to provide some values from a game market into c# objects. I am fairly new to c# and haven't worked with API's before.

Heres my code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HttpsApiTest
{
    class Program
    {

        public class ForQuery
        {
            public static bool bid { get; set; }
            public static List<int> types { get; set; }
            public static List<object> regions { get; set; }
            public static List<object> systems { get; set; }
            public static int hours { get; set; }
            public static int minq { get; set; }
        }

        public class Buy
        {
            public static ForQuery forQuery { get; set; }
            public static long volume { get; set; }
            public static double wavg { get; set; }
            public static double avg { get; set; }
            public static double variance { get; set; }
            public static double stdDev { get; set; }
            public static double median { get; set; }
            public static double fivePercent { get; set; }
            public static double max { get; set; }
            public static double min { get; set; }
            public static bool highToLow { get; set; }
            public static long generated { get; set; }
        }

        public class ForQuery2
        {
            public static bool bid { get; set; }
            public static List<int> types { get; set; }
            public static List<object> regions { get; set; }
            public static List<object> systems { get; set; }
            public static int hours { get; set; }
            public static int minq { get; set; }
        }

        public class Sell
        {
            public ForQuery2 forQuery { get; set; }
            public static int volume { get; set; }
            public static double wavg { get; set; }
            public static double avg { get; set; }
            public static double variance { get; set; }
            public static double stdDev { get; set; }
            public static double median { get; set; }
            public static double fivePercent { get; set; }
            public static double max { get; set; }
            public static double min { get; set; }
            public static bool highToLow { get; set; }
            public static long generated { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public Buy buy { get; set; }
            public Sell sell { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sURL = "https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat/json?typeid=1230&regionlimit=10000002";
            StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(sURL).GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            string sLine = objReader.ReadLine();

            JToken.Parse(sLine.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "")).ToObject<RootObject>();

            Console.WriteLine(Buy.max);
            Console.WriteLine(Buy.highToLow);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

and the web api JSON outputs this:

```
[
  {
    "buy": {
      "forQuery": {
        "bid": true,
        "types": [
          1230
        ],
        "regions": [],
        "systems": [],
        "hours": 24,
        "minq": 1
      },
      "volume": 5544790080,
      "wavg": 11.43,
      "avg": 10.86,
      "variance": 4.38,
      "stdDev": 2.09,
      "median": 12,
      "fivePercent": 13.75,
      "max": 20,
      "min": 5,
      "highToLow": true,
      "generated": 1551926105235
    },
    "sell": {
      "forQuery": {
        "bid": false,
        "types": [
          1230
        ],
        "regions": [],
        "systems": [],
        "hours": 24,
        "minq": 1
      },
      "volume": 258207299,
      "wavg": 16.8,
      "avg": 20.21,
      "variance": 132.71,
      "stdDev": 11.52,
      "median": 15.99,
      "fivePercent": 12.92,
      "max": 60,
      "min": 6,
      "highToLow": false,
      "generated": 1551926105235
    }
  }
]
```

I am not sure why `Console.WriteLine(Buy.max);` shows as 0 instead of 20 and `Console.WriteLine(Buy.highToLow);` shows as false instead of true. what am I doing wrong? I have looked for solutions to this issue for the past few hours to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are all your properties static?  Try removing static from properties.

Comment: Why are you're trying to remove pieces of the JSON. Don't do that. It's a valid JSON. Read the stream to the end the deserialize to a simpler class structure. Your `Buy` and `Sell` classes are identical, so is the `ForQuery` class. You can have just one type of each. You could just use the Properties names (Buy and Sell) to tell apart the two objects. That's all.

Comment: Also, you can use an attribute `[JsonProperty("[OriginalPropertyName]")]` if you need to change the name of a property.

Comment: I used static because the way my code was setup, it threw an error saying it couldn't use a non-static value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What they said:

- Static members are usually for helpers or factory methods, or constants
- The API is returning an array (or List)
- That string-foo replacement is just sketchy at best. Any time you are working with a standard like JSON or XML, use the libraries to convert it to an object, then manipulate

Here's a working snippet:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HttpsApiTest
{
    class Program
    {

        public class ForQuery
        {
            public bool bid { get; set; }
            public List<int> types { get; set; }
            public List<object> regions { get; set; }
            public List<object> systems { get; set; }
            public int hours { get; set; }
            public int minq { get; set; }
        }

        public class Buy
        {
            public ForQuery forQuery { get; set; }
            public long volume { get; set; }
            public double wavg { get; set; }
            public double avg { get; set; }
            public double variance { get; set; }
            public double stdDev { get; set; }
            public double median { get; set; }
            public double fivePercent { get; set; }
            public double max { get; set; }
            public double min { get; set; }
            public bool highToLow { get; set; }
            public long generated { get; set; }
        }

        public class ForQuery2
        {
            public bool bid { get; set; }
            public List<int> types { get; set; }
            public List<object> regions { get; set; }
            public List<object> systems { get; set; }
            public int hours { get; set; }
            public int minq { get; set; }
        }

        public class Sell
        {
            public ForQuery2 forQuery { get; set; }
            public int volume { get; set; }
            public double wavg { get; set; }
            public double avg { get; set; }
            public double variance { get; set; }
            public double stdDev { get; set; }
            public double median { get; set; }
            public double fivePercent { get; set; }
            public double max { get; set; }
            public double min { get; set; }
            public bool highToLow { get; set; }
            public long generated { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public Buy buy { get; set; }
            public Sell sell { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sURL = "https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat/json?typeid=1230&regionlimit=10000002";
            StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(sURL).GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            string sLine = objReader.ReadLine();

            var obj = JToken.Parse(sLine).ToObject<List<RootObject>>();

            Console.WriteLine("Buy node:");

            Console.WriteLine(" Max: " + obj[0].buy.max);
            Console.WriteLine(" HighToLow: " + obj[0].buy.highToLow);

            Console.WriteLine("Sell node:");

            Console.WriteLine(" Max: " + obj[0].sell.max);
            Console.WriteLine(" HighToLow: " + obj[0].sell.highToLow);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The string replace is going to remove all instances of square brackets. You'd be better off deserializing the response as a list of RootObjects.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Data
    {
        public string DataPoint;
    }

    class CustomData
    {
        public Data Dp;
    }

    class Utility
    {
        public T JsonDeserialisation<T>(string jsonFile)
        {
            TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(jsonFile);
            JsonTextReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(textReader);
            return JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
        }
    }
```

Since you have all classes beforehand, you can the following code [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) json deserializer. Here 'T' is CustomData class