# parse json response c#

Tags: c#, json, parsing, post

I have created small class

```
class JsonResponse
{
    public string Response { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my program I send some json data and wait store reply to the following variable

```
var ResultJSON = Post(uri, values);
```

while parsing I get

> Service Error: Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type
>   'App.someclass+JsonResponse'

Comment: Please refer answers of the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55036305/json-api-values-0-or-false) to get answer

Comment: I don't understand that one, can you modify my code ?

Comment: Had simple error which is not connected to initial question. please close and delete

Answer (score 0):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class JsonResponse
{
    public string Response { get; set; }
}

class Utility
{
    public JsonResponse JsonDeserialisation(string response)
    {
        TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(response);
        JsonTextReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(textReader);
        return JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize<JsonResponse>(jsonReader);
    }
}
class Main
{
    static void Program()
    {
        var ResultJSON = "Json String received from post";//Post(uri, values);
        var deserialisedJson = Utility.JsonDeserialisation(ResultJSON);
    }
}
```

Add newtonSoft.json nuget package to project

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may give your JSON file to result variable.

```
var result = Convert.ToString(ResultJSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

try
`var Result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<JsonResponse>(ResultJSON.**Response**);`

looks to me that you are trying to deserialize from an object rather than the string response

Answer (score 0):

Try using `using newtonsoft.json` downloadable [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) or use the nuget package.

It has a function that does exactly what you want. Expecting the result of the `Post` is in string format of course.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponse>(ResultJSON);
```

Your `JsonResponse` class must look exacly the same as the json your getting. So make sure if you get more data in the json that you want to save in the class the names are the same.

If you have anymore questions feel free to ask.